# How to convert file from windows utf-16 or windows utf-8 to unix utf-16 with C++

Tags: c++, windows, unix, utf-8, utf-16

Now, we use C++ on windows deal with some data. We have to convert some files to unix uft-16's xmls, the xml files are stored on a Unix server.

So I want to kown how to convert file from windows utf-16 or windows utf-8 to unix utf-16 using C++ ?

Comment: What are the problems encountered when trying to use directly on Unix utf16 xml files produced on Windows ?

Comment: The only possibility I can think of is that the UNIX system is expecting UTF-16BE whereas Windows generally uses UTF-16LE.  As far as I know, conversion is just a matter of swapping each byte pair around.  (If possible, the safest approach would probably be to transmit the files in UTF-8 format and then convert that to UTF-16 on the UNIX system.)

Answer (score 0):

std::codecvt_utf8_utf16 which requires codecvt header can be used to convert UTF-8 to UTF-16. A Sample from [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/codecvt/codecvt_utf8_utf16/). A compiler which supports C++11 is required.

```
// codecvt_utf8_utf16 example
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>

int main ()
{
  std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>,char16_t> conversion;
  std::string mbs = conversion.to_bytes( u"\u4f60\u597d" );  // ni hao (你好)

  // print out hex value of each byte:
  std::cout << std::hex;
  for (int i=0; i<mbs.length(); ++i)
    std::cout << int(unsigned char(mbs[i])) << ' ';
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

More information can be found in the above mentioned link.